# How to estimate the peak power of BLE?

Tags: power, batteries, low-power, bluetooth-low-energy

I am trying to determine my battery sizing for the NRF52840 BLE. To do so, I want to estimate the peak power. But I am struggling with this.

Is it safe to go with transmit current as the peak current and then just multiply with the voltage to get estimate peak power?

So in the case of the NRF52840, the peak power I am thinking would be 6.4 mA x 3V = 19.2 mW. The values I got are on page [58](https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/pdf/nRF52840_PS_v1.1.pdf), 1Mbs BLE, DC/DC on

Answer (score 0):

You probably should rely on average power instead of peak power, unless you want to use full power all the time (BLE typically is used to send small packets of data and sleep most of the time).

Have you seen this or similar video? 
https://youtu.be/nyWMaAF4dRQ

It shows how other wireless modules consume energy (average is very small compared to peak and it depends a lot on how you use module).

Maybe just take some small battery with known capacity, repeat (and count) data transfer operations until battery discharges completely, or discharges to some voltage.

Comment: Yes, average power is important for battery life but so is peak power for sizing the battery. I basically want to make sure the battery can provide the peak power. So is the way I calculated peak power correct?

Comment: Power is voltage x current, so yes. Momentary power during data transfer is calculated correctly. But I think you are calculating wrong thing. Battery ratings are usually like "maximum current", not "maximum power". And if you transmit for few milliseconds you can probably overload battery for few milliseconds.

Comment: Right, so maximum current or power would for the BLE NRF52840 be when it transmits, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for peak power as you did, it's the product of the maximum current consumed and supply voltage. For the maximum current consumed, you'll have to add up all the various parts of the SoC that would be ON. For example when transmitting at 0 dBm with 1 Mbps for BLE, if a high frequency TIMER would need to be ON, its current consumption would need to be added too (detailed in section 5.2.1.9).

For reference section 5.2.1.11 provides the total current consumption in a few scenarios. Is1 of 8.6 mA would be a good value to use as there is a good chance the processor also will be working when using the radio. This will give a peak power of 8.6x3 = 25.8 mW.

[image]

Comment: CoreMark is a benchmark for CPU performance, I don't think I will be running that. And the 6.4mA accounts for the HFXO (high frequency clock) as on so I think that encapsulates that?

Comment: Its just that they are running CoreMark, the processor can be running anything. I feel it'll be hard to be absolutely sure that the processor won't be running any code when the radio is operating, so this 5.2.1.11 is a good indication of the peak current consumption. Yes, as you say the 6.4 mA also considers the HFXO current too. My bad, I'll edit that.